# "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report" on Previews xcode 12.4

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I am getting a swift complier error : "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report" when making a preview, on this section of code:

```
struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView(currentuserDetail: AllUsers, imageURL: String)
            .previewDevice("iPhone 12 Pro Max")
    }
}
```

on the line

> static var previews: some View {

I don't know what can be done to fix this , and these are the variables in the view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
@EnvironmentObject var details: UserDetails

@State var currentuserDetail : AllUsers
@State private var alertMessage: String = ""
@State private var showAlert: Bool = false

@State var imageURL : String
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

Comment: You shoudl add the environment objects to the preview as you have added them to the apps ContentView in the @main struct of SwiftUI. And you should put actual values in the View: ProfileView(currentuserDetail: allUsersInstance, imageURL: urlString)